# Method entry points in a class variable

Tags: python, python-2.x

How can I go about installing as a class variable a table that contains the entry points to the methods?

For clarification, consider the following -working- code:

```
class A(object):

    def go(self, n):
        method = self.table[n]
        method(self)

    def add(self):
        print "add"

    def multiply(self):
        print "multiply"

    table = {
        1: add,
        2: multiply,
        }

>>> q = A()
>>> q.go(1)
add
```

However, I don't like it much. I would like to have the table at the beginning for readability (the real world project is much bigger) and I don't like the call using `method(self)`. I think it's very confusing.

My question is: Is there a better way or is the above code spot-on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It already contains one. It's called `__dict__`.

```
class foo(object):
    def go(self, method):
        getattr(self, method)()

    def a(self):
        ...

    def b(self):
        ...
```

If you reaaaally want numeric indices, you can do e.g.

```
class foo(object):
    methods = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }
    def go(self, n):
        getattr(self, self.methods[n])()
```

But that's just silly, especially that strings are interned and using magic integers in place of them doesn't buy you much, except for obscurity.

Comment: I don't need numeric indices, in fact they are strings, but I do need the keys to be different than method names because they may contain characters not valid in Python, several keys may map to the same method, etc. That said, the second snippet looks good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get why you want to do that, but you could solve it differently like this:

```
class A(object):

    table = {
        1: "add",
        2: "multiply",
        }

    def go(self, n):
        method = getattr(self, self.table[n])
        method()

    def add(self):
        print "add"

    def multiply(self):
        print "multiply"

>>> a = A()
>>> a.go(1)
add
```

**Edit after reading your response to Cat Plus Plus:**

If you just want aliases to existing methods, there's a far easier way to do that -- maybe you want to be able to call those methods in Welsh:

```
class A(object):

    table = {
        1: "add",
        2: "multiply",
        }

    def go(self, n):
        method = getattr(self, self.table[n])
        method()

    def add(self):
        print "add"

    def multiply(self):
        print "multiply"

    ychwanegu = add
    lluosi = multiply

>>> a = A()
>>> a.lluosi()
multiply
```